# Why can I only see an upper triangular matrix via view_model?

Tags: openmdao

I used two of the examples (single [ActDisk](http://openmdao.org/twodocs/versions/latest/examples/betz_limit/betz.html) and multi disciplinary [Sellar](http://openmdao.org/twodocs/versions/latest/basic_guide/first_mdao.html?highlight=sellar) problems) to understand  the [view_model](http://openmdao.org/twodocs/versions/latest/features/debugging/om_command.html?highlight=view_model) feature.

According to the theory manual on [linear solvers](http://openmdao.org/twodocs/versions/latest/theory_manual/total_derivs/setup_linear_solvers.html) I should be able to see the matrix system built for unified derivatives. It is not clear why I am not able to see the lower triangle matrix even though I set prob.setup(mode='fwd'). For the uncoupled model ([ActDisk](http://openmdao.org/twodocs/versions/latest/examples/betz_limit/betz.html)) I do not change the solver so it should be the LinearRunOnce. I set the prob.setup mode to forward and  I get this warning which is fine, but I still see a upper triangular matrix, as if it is being treated reverse mode.

```
 \anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openmdao\core\problem.py:850: RuntimeWarning: Inefficient choice of derivative mode.  You chose 'fwd' for a problem with 2 design variables and 1 response variables (objectives and nonlinear constraints).                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     (mode, desvar_size, response_size), RuntimeWarning)
```

In the second example ([Sellar](http://openmdao.org/twodocs/versions/latest/basic_guide/first_mdao.html?highlight=sellar)) the cycle group of the coupled model  has its own non linear solver but no extra linear solver (note that : i am using the example as is from the webpage). This can be an issue, but my focus is on the  'model-group' (highest in the hierarchy) which is still connected to the default linear solver. (if i understand correctly even though the subsystems contain cycles, LinearRunOnce should work on the highest level of hierarchy as long as that one does not have a cycle).  Similar to the previous case I see the same N2 diagram no matter what I set the problem model. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The n2 viewer does not show the actual jacobian matrix. it always shows in DSM format, which is actually the transpose jacobian.

You won't see an change in the view_model when you change the linear solver.